# In a mobile messaging app, should sending a message be triggered from the server or the client?

Tags: iphone, mobile, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In apps like Snapchat, Line, Kik, Groupme, etc., users have their contact list from which they can send messages to multiple people.

I'm building a messaging app that has similar features and at first was going to just add a server and let the server store device tokens and send notifications from the server. (By the way I am using Urban Airship to send push notifications.) So the way I had imagined was like this:

1. User A writes "Hi there" to User B
2. "Hi there" gets posted to my server where it gets stored in DB for later retrieval
3. After 2 is successful, the server posts "Hi there" to Urban Airship server (Server has the contact list which has all the device id info)

Then I realized how this could be done client side as well, that is, if it's ok to store device tokens of a user's contacts on their apps. So this is how it would work:

1. User A writes "Hi there" to User B
2. "Hi there" gets posted to my server where it will be stored in DB for later retrieval
3. After 2 is successful, the client (iPhone) posts "Hi there" directly to Urban Airship server (The app stores all of the user's contacts' device ids in core data)

I'm a newbie at push notification so don't even know if it's safe/ok to store device tokens on the client side, but I feel like it would be much more efficient in terms of server load (my server) since all the push notifications requests are sent from the client. Any suggestions on what the best practice is? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this sounds like a very bad idea.
1. When a user joins the network you need to publish the token to all users connected to it.
if you have great amount of new users, its not so smart.
2. A simple sniffer (Network sniffer \ openSSH sniffer) can detect users tokens.
Security wise, it's not a good idea.
3. Also, it's overloading the user's device.
Rule of thumb, all overhead should be handled by the server.
Consider this:

## -User A send "Hi there" to user B

1. User A sends the msg to the server
2. Server saves the msg + sends "OK" to user A
3. User A receives the "OK" and now sends the msg again, now to user B
4. User B gets the msg and sends to user A "OK".
   How will you know the msg got to user B? will he send an "OK" to the server as well?

To make things short,
Go with the first method, the second one is very not recommended..

Good luck :-)

Comment: Your comment on security issue makes sense. That's why I asked, since I don't know so much about the implication of device tokens being exposed. Is it bad? What can be done with the device token? I ask because I thought just having device token doesn't help you with anything--the user has to give permission to an app for the app to start sending push notifications

Comment: And regarding the first point, you don't necessarily have to publish all the tokens to every device. Let's say I have 200 friends, I only need device tokens for those 200 friends. So whenever I open the app, it could fetch the server for the list of 200 friends (or if there's any new friend signed up) and then store just those 200, not the entire user base.

Comment: If I have the tokens, what do I need you and your server for? I can send msgs directly to all my friends.. Ad I still belive you need the server.. The option to have tokens dosent let you the option to send Token2Token msging.. you need a server in the middle. and security wise, if I have your token, I can pretend to be you with your token and get your msgs and send on your belhaf.. think about it :-) (And vote if the answer helped you :-))

Comment: Hmm that's a good question. I was picturing the server as the central repository for the entire relationship graph and each device synchronizes contacts list based on that. And also for persistence. Think about how stuff on our iPhones used to be all decentralized and they used to all go away when we remove the app, etc. But with iCloud all we need to do is reset the phone and connect with iCloud account and it's very easy to recover--all our contacts, documents, apps, etc.

Comment: Exactly, on the iCloud we need a user password and email in order to pretend to be him and still his info.. If you give away the tokens, what security do you have? You are catually giving every user a set of keys to homes that are not yours (your users home). they can use these keys to break to theyre homes and get info like msgs, contact lists and more..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apple Push Notifications service, you should definitely send the notifications from the server to the devices, and not directly from device A to device B. Apart from the reasons mentioned in the other answer, there is the issue of maintaining a connection with the APNS servers.

If each device can send its messages directly to APNS, each device would have to maintain its own TLS connection to APNS servers. And since devices often connect and disconnect from the internet, that connection would close and reopen frequently. Multiply that by the number of devices on which your app is installed, and you will have a large number of short lived connections to APNS. That would probably get your certificate revoked.

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1))